# pyinstallerでコンパイルしたexeファイルが正常に動作しない

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

pyjoystickでコントローラーの入力テスターを作ろうとしています。
vscodeで実行したときには入力したボタンが表示されるのですが、pyinstallerでコンパイルしたexeファイルを実行すると入力したボタンが表示されません。(関数が読み込まれていない) どうすれば治りますでしょうか。

以下がpyjoystick公式のサンプルコードです。これをそのままpyinstallerでコンパイルして実行しようとしました。

```
from pyjoystick.sdl2 import Key, Joystick, run_event_loop

def print_add(joy):
    print('Added', joy)

def print_remove(joy):
    print('Removed', joy)

def key_received(key):
    print('Key:', key)
    if key.keytype == Key.BUTTON and key.number == 0:
        if key.value == 1:
            # Button 0 pressed
            print("Do action!")
        else:
            # Button 0 released
            pass

run_event_loop(print_add, print_remove, key_received)
```

vscodeで実行した場合のコンソール

```
Added 
Key: Button 0
Do action!   
Key: Button 0
```

pyinstallerでコンパイルしたexeで実行した場合のコンソール

```
Added
```

どちらもpyjoystickがコントローラーを検知した後、コントローラーのAボタンを押しています。

Comment: 実行環境は何でしょうか？ 「exeで」とあるので Windowsかもだけど環境記したほうがよいでしょう。何を目的として pyinstaller使ってるのか不明だけど, 場合によっては(例えばコンパクトにしたいなどの目的なら) 別の手段も考えてよいのでは？

Comment: すみません。その通りです。windowsのandconda3で動かしています。(バージョン3.11.5) exe化の目的は、単にpythonが入っていないPCでもファイル1個でプログラムを動かしたいという物です。(そのためpyinstallerの--onefileオプションを使っています。)

Comment: zipファイルとプログラムの 2つほどで提供(pyjoystick があるので +α)。展開して実行できるけど必要なくなれば展開したディレクトリーまるごと削除で OK, なら回答できますが, それは問題ありますか？

Comment: pyinstallerの--add-binary オプションを使い、pyjoystick、sdl2のdllを追加する事で、exeファイルでも動作する様になりました！コメント頂きありがとうございました。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローはQ&Aサイトであり, 「自分の質問に対して、自分で回答しても大丈夫です。」(https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)。詳しくは [自分の質問に回答できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)にも載ってます。(絶対すべきとかじゃないけれど, ナレッジベースとして)

Comment: 分かりました。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

下記のいずれかをpyinstallerでのコンパイル時にオプション指定することで、問題を解決することが出来ました。

`<venv_folder>` には、python.exeがある場所を入れました。
例: `C:\Users\<ユーザー名>\anaconda3`

**32bitの場合:**

```
--add-binary "<venv_folder>\Lib\site-packages\pyjoystick\sdl2_win32\SDL2.dll:pyjoystick\sdl2_win32"
```

**64bitの場合:**

```
--add-binary "<venv_folder>\Lib\site-packages\pyjoystick\sdl2_win64\SDL2.dll:pyjoystick\sdl2_win64"
```